# Border widths displays inconsistently

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, styles, border

Lets take this as example. I now have a total of 8 textboxes. I use a static resource style to make sure they all have the exact same styling set. But notice how some of the textboxes have a bottom border line and others don't. Why does this happen?

[image]
Here's the code

```
<Style x:Key="AddressTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">            
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="230"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="260"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="45"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,2,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>

<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="5">
            <StackPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7">Postal</TextBlock>
                        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>                                            
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="10"></DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7">Street</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Height="Auto">
                    <TextBlock Width="50" Margin="7"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"></TextBox>
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: The BorderThickness is BorderThickness="0,0,0,2" on the first PaymentTerms TextBox, but BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" on the other ones ?

Comment: Hi SvenG - sorry, that was a typo - after correcting though, problem still exists.

Comment: What is your surrounding Panel? I have copy/pasted your code in a an empty form with a StackPanel `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">` and it looks fine ..

Comment: For `TextBox`, which "looks thicker" trying use `SnapsToDevicePixels=True`.

Comment: Copy/Pasted your new markup and it also looks fine on my PC. I assume you have some stuff around it that prevents your DockPanel to use up all your space and due to size calc issues some pixels are cropped. Have you tried your example code in a blank new WPF application?
Also which Specs do you have (.net/OS) - as the text seems to be blurry there definitely is a Pixel drawing issue. Have you tried the SnapsToDevicePixels suggested by @AnatoliyNikolaev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your layout is very inefficient, its not the problem as all above comments suggest. Nothing to do with `SnapToDevicePixels`, `Padding`, `Margins`, etc. It is part of `TextBox'`s control style. It seems that if you set `BorderWidth` bigger than default, it sticks on all corners, but if you go below it doesn't. If you extract the `TextBox`'s template you can see its border and styling. So in order to "beat" this irregularity, instead of trying to sort of indirectly manipulate the `TextBox`'s `Border` properties in your style you need to override its template. Then manipulate it's `Border` directly in the `Template`.

Here's a the style that will work(I plugged in your setters into it) :

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="LightGray"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="Gray"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EnabledBackgroundBrush" Color="White"/>

    <Style x:Key="AddressTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="230"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="260"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1,2,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2"  Padding="2" Background="{StaticResource EnabledBackgroundBrush}" 
                            BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

also, just a tip about your layout. To minimize inefficiencies, I would use the `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Postal"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Street" Margin="7,10,7,7"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="5"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="6"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="7"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"  Style="{StaticResource AddressTextBox}"/>
    </Grid>
```